# Can I automatically change my dock preferences when connected to a cinema display?

Tags: dock, cinema-display

Desired behavior:

- when MBP connected to cinema display: do not show / hide dock
- when MBP not connected to cinema display: show / hide dock

Possible?

Comment: Just for clarity... When your Mac is connected to the Cinema Display you'd like the dock to stay on screen.  When your Mac is not connected to an external display you'd like the dock to hide automatically.  Correct?  (I don't have an answer, just looking for clarity on that)

Comment: I suppose You would need to write an Agent for this. It would need to listen to notifications (here's  example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042641/notification-when-display-gets-connected-or-disconnected ) and hide/show Dock when it arrives. You can achieve it by sending ⌘⌥D key shortcut.